# ascii value and symbols of few extended ascii charactes like euro sign

Tags: c++, c, ascii, extended-ascii

I am confused with two different asciii values of some charactes which I am trying to handle.I have to allow the charactes from 128 to 170 ascii values in c. But when euro sing comes it parses value to 8364 instead of 128. same problem is with charactes till 159 ..then from 160 I am getting the corrrect values. 
I am little confused with the output of the simple code.

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <wchar.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    wchar_t nwchar = 128;

    setlocale(LC_ALL, "en_US.utf8");
    while (nwchar < 255) {
        wprintf(L"\n string is [%d][%lc]", nwchar, nwchar);
        nwchar += 1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

> OUTPUT:  string is [128][�]  string is [129][�]
>
> string is [130][�]
>
> string is [131][�]
>
> string is [132][�]
>
> till 159 then
>
> string is [160][ ]
>
> string is [161][¡]
>
> string is [162][¢]
>
> string is [163][£]
>
> string is [164][¤]
>
> string is [165][¥]

so from 160 the correct symbol is printed.

I looked at following link for extended ascii :
https://www.ascii-code.com/
so for 128 value euro symbol should have appeared.

I tried for some web coding for generating the symbol and I got .

code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>I will display &euro;</p>
<p>I will display &#8364;</p>
<p>I will display &#128;</p>
<p>I will display &#x0080;</p>
<p>I will display &#x20AC;</p>

</body>
</html>
```

output:

> I will display €
>
> I will display €
>
> I will display €
>
> I will display €
>
> I will display €

now I am confused as how same symbol is printed for different values.

the number 8364 or 0x20AC I got through C code for  € .
I used following code

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <wchar.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "en_US.utf8");

    wchar_t nwchar = 128;
    wchar_t nwchar1;
    unsigned char ch[] = "€";
    int sz = 0;

    //setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
    while (nwchar < 130) {
        wprintf(L"\n string is [%d][%lc]", nwchar, nwchar);
        nwchar += 1;
    }

    sz = mblen(&ch[0], MB_CUR_MAX);
    int t = mbtowc(&nwchar1, &ch, sz);
    wprintf(L"\n string is[%d] [%d][%lc]", sz, nwchar1, nwchar1);

    return 0;
}
```

and got  following output.

> string is [128][]
>                                                                                                                      string is [129][] 
>                                                                                                                        string is[3] [8364][€]

All the C code above and its output is from linux redhat and I have also tried it on [ https://www.onlinegdb.com/ ] which gave the same output on its terminal  .

now how to handle the euro symbol or similar values which falls below 155 because when I am receiving the value it is different as in euro symbol it was 8364.

am i missing something basics of encoding?

My requirement is how do I get 128 for € or 131 for ƒ and similar symbols till 159 as per ascii-code.com in c code.
I need to handle the extended ascii symbols so I need the C code so that when I handle these symbols
 I get 128 for € instead of 8364 or 131 for ƒ instead of 402.If someone could help me with sample C code.

Comment: "128 to 170 ascii values" -> no such thing I'm afraid.

Comment: What operating system are you programming for? What terminal program is handling the output?

Comment: Oh and note that `128` is not a valid single-byte UTF-8 character. Only plain 7-bit ASCII (with the eight bit set to zero) is valid as single-byte UTF-8 encoded characters.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude : I am working on redhat linux and all the sample programs i have tried on onlinegdb [https://www.onlinegdb.com/].On ascii 128 I am agree but how does two values print (128) and (1364) prints euro symbol.what ascii value should I consider for it. Moreover 128-159 have same issue.

Comment: @Bathsheba 128-255 falls under extended ascii .I am trying to handle it and from 161 to 255 I am able to do it well .But if I try to handle the symbols of [ https://www.ascii-code.com/ ] from 128 to 159 I get different value and print of my output does not match with it till 159 . why this weird behavior for 128 to 159 .

Comment: What's the *locale* for "extended-ASCII"?

Comment: @pmg in my actual project its Windows-1252  but in the above code its utf-8 at the beginning so ever thing below is same.

Comment: what is printed, for any specific value, depends on which [code page](https://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=description+of+code+page&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8) is a active

Comment: There is no such thing as "extended ASCII". There are many different (mutually incompatible) extensions of ASCII, including Unicode. ASCII itself only goes from 0 to 127. The Unicode code point for € is indeed 8364. Why do you think this is wrong?

Comment: @melpomeme because 128 also prints the same symbol in the above html code and it is corresponding to 128 as per [ ascii-code.com ] .This is the issue is with symbols from 128 to 159.My question is how do I get 128 for € or 131 for ƒ and similar symbols till 159 as per ascii-code.com. I need the C code so that when I handle these symbols I get 128 for  € instead of 8364 or 131 for  ƒ instead of 402.If you could help me with sample C code.

Comment: [Read This](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/).